# Nginx add subdirectory to proxy_pass response?

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having an issue with my Nginx configuration and I could use a little help since I feel I am so close.

I am trying to configure Nginx to host multiple applications and routing the traffic based on an applications subdirectory as shown here.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /something / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    rewrite /something/(.*)$ /$1 break;   
    proxy_pass http://django_application_upstream1; 
    }

    location /another_something/ / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    rewrite /another_something /(.*)$ /$1 break;   
    proxy_pass http://django_application_upstream2; 
    }
}
```

This set up works great for directing traffic to the respective applications but when a user clicks on a href with an absolute URL everything goes wrong.

For example:

```
    http://django_application_upstream1/something/ -> Landing page (perfect)
    user clicks landing page href=’/’ -> 404 not found 
(should return user to http://django_application_upstream1/something/)
```

Even when I add the subdirectory to the href (‘/something/’) within the application html the subdirectory is removed somewhere along the way and I still end back up at the root url.

**Is it possible to rewrite a proxy_pass response so I can add back the subdirectory that I removed with the previous rewrite?
This would mean all responses from the proxy have the subdirectory added back even if an absolute href was being used.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can’t you solve your issue using html ? You could play with the base tag ! For more info check out https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base